# facebook plugin for cordova returning a "No active session" alert

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-facebook-plugin, cordova-facebook

I am working on an android project which has a feature to share a message to Facebook user's wall. I added phonegap-facebook-plugin to my project successfully.

I am trying to share a message to my wall. But I get an alert message "No active session". This is the code which I followed from [Github](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin)

```
facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog( 
{
    method: "feed",
    picture:'https://www.google.co.jp/logos/doodles/2014/doodle-4-google-2014-japan-winner-5109465267306496.2-hp.png',
    name:'Test Post',
    message:'First photo post',    
    caption: 'Testing using phonegap plugin',
    description: 'Posting photo using phonegap facebook plugin'
}, 
function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
```

Comment: Same problem here, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but only in Android devices. Someone advised me to use "method: share" for "method: feed" and it works fine, but the problem remains.

Comment: Same problem here! Only happens in some Android devices. Did you find any solution?

Comment: The problem was with the key hash that was generated. Once I mapped the app Id with the right key hash, it worked fine.